# Procedurally generated buttons in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So, I want that my buttons call a function when released, so that my labels come up visible.
As you can see the button's on_release is set to buttonPress where I wanted to do this, but whichever button I press it passes the last label into the function. How can I fix this? Is there a better way to do this?

```py
    def buttonPress(self, label):
        print("hi")
        print(label)
        label.height = '50dp'
        label.font_size = '20sp'


    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        mainLayout = RelativeLayout()
        self.add_widget(mainLayout)
        scroll = ScrollView(do_scroll_x = False,pos_hint={"top":0.8,"center_x":0.75})
        infoLayout = GridLayout(cols = 1, size_hint = (0.5, None))
        mainLayout.add_widget(scroll)
        scroll.add_widget(infoLayout)

        files = glob.glob("user/*.txt")
        InfoWidgetButtonArray = []
        InfoWidgetLabelArray = []

        for x in range(len(files)):
            InfoWidgetLabelArray.append(Label(text="hello mate", size_hint_y=None,height = '0dp', font_size='0sp', color = (0, 0, 0, 1), id=str(x)))
            print(InfoWidgetLabelArray[x])
            InfoWidgetButtonArray.append(Button(text=files[x][5:][:-4], font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=30,on_release=lambda lambdaFunction: self.buttonPress(InfoWidgetLabelArray[x])))
            infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetButtonArray[x])
            infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetLabelArray[x])
```

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

class InfoScreen(Screen, Widget):
    new = True
    def buttonPress(self, label):
        print("hi")
        print(label)
        label.height = '50dp'
        label.font_size = '20sp'


    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        mainLayout = RelativeLayout()
        self.add_widget(mainLayout)
        scroll = ScrollView(do_scroll_x = False,pos_hint={"top":0.8,"center_x":0.75})
        infoLayout = GridLayout(cols = 1, size_hint = (0.5, None))
        mainLayout.add_widget(scroll)
        scroll.add_widget(infoLayout)


        InfoWidgetButtonArray = []
        InfoWidgetLabelArray = []

        for x in range(2):
            InfoWidgetLabelArray.append(Label(text="hello mate", size_hint_y=None,height = '0dp', font_size='0sp', color = (0, 0, 0, 1), id=str(x)))
            print(InfoWidgetLabelArray[x])
            InfoWidgetButtonArray.append(Button(text="name"+str(x), font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=30,on_release=lambda lambdaFunction: self.buttonPress(InfoWidgetLabelArray[x])))
            infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetButtonArray[x])
            infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetLabelArray[x])


        SpacingButton = Button(text='Hello world', font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=50, color=(0, 0, 0, 0), background_color=(0,0,0,0))
        infoLayout.add_widget(SpacingButton)

        infoLayout.bind(minimum_height=infoLayout.setter('height'))



sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(InfoScreen(name='Info'))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: You've hit [this common gotcha](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) - see the link for solution, or there are many SO answers about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the **partial** function from the **functools** module. It binds the input in your for loop and returns the actual function you want it to have.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from functools import partial #Changed This

Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

class InfoScreen(Screen, Widget):
    new = True
    def buttonPress(self, label, *args):
        print("hi")
        print(label)
        label.height = '50dp'
        label.font_size = '20sp'

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        mainLayout = RelativeLayout()
        self.add_widget(mainLayout)
        scroll = ScrollView(do_scroll_x = False, pos_hint={"top":0.8,"center_x":0.75}, size_hint_max_y=300) #To enable scrolling be sure to set a maximal value, or have enough buttons to cover the whole window
        infoLayout = GridLayout(cols = 1, size_hint = (0.5, None))
        mainLayout.add_widget(scroll)
        scroll.add_widget(infoLayout)


        InfoWidgetButtonArray = []
        InfoWidgetLabelArray = []

        for x in range(5):
            InfoWidgetLabelArray.append(Label(text="hello mate", size_hint_y=None,height = '0dp', font_size='0sp', color = (0, 0, 0, 1), id=str(x)))
            print(InfoWidgetLabelArray[x])
            InfoWidgetButtonArray.append(Button(text="name"+str(x), font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=30, on_release=partial(self.buttonPress, InfoWidgetLabelArray[x]))) #Changed This
            infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetButtonArray[x])
            infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetLabelArray[x])


        SpacingButton = Button(text='Hello world', font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=50, color=(0, 0, 0, 0), background_color=(0,0,0,0))
        infoLayout.add_widget(SpacingButton)

        infoLayout.bind(minimum_height=infoLayout.setter('height'))

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(InfoScreen(name='Info'))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Hope this is what you were looking for, I spent some time rereading the question before I hopefully understood.